# Webdriver Wait for TEXT to Appear

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, wait

I'm unable to click on an element within a list, once i have clicked on the dropdown list?

Method I have created which Doesn't work.

```
public static void waitForTextToAppearAndClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, String textToAppear) throws InterruptedException{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    WebElement locator = element; 
    locator.click();

    WebElement textToClick =  driver.findElement(By.linkText(textToAppear));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(textToClick));
    textToClick.click();
}
```

Using `thread.sleep` seems to works but I don't want to use this method, can anybody recommend a way to wait and click on a specific text element once I have clicked on the primary button?

```
public static void waitForTextToAppearAndClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, String textToAppear) throws InterruptedException{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    WebElement locator = element; 
    locator.click();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(textToAppear)).click();;

}
```

**Please note I need to click on BBQ Sauce, the `thread.sleep()` is successful when needing to click on BBQ Sauce**

[image]

Thanks your for help

Comment: can you also add the exception trace for our reference?

Comment: Use the existing ExpectedConditions like -  textToBePresentInElement or  textToBePresentInElementValue. Check the API --  textToBePresentInElement.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML.

Comment: thanks for the help, but the issue is still there, @Grasshopper if i use ** 'wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(cyoPage.dropdown_Sauce, "BBQ Sauce")); ' ** but click on the element **'cyoPage.dropdown_Sauce'** it throws a 'null pointer exception' however if i solely use the method above it will not click on the dropdown menu at all which in turn stops the program from clicking on 'BBQ Sauce'

Comment: Hi @JeffC probably easier to access the html via the following:1. access: https://www.pizzahut.co.uk/ | 2. Enter postcode and localise to any store | 3. click on Pizza Page | 4. Select CYO1 and click on button add to basket | 5. You will then see the 'Sauce dropdown button'

Comment: You need to first click on the 'Sauce' dropdown and then wait for the text. Make sure you wait on the webelement which is supposed to contain the text and not on the dropdown text.

Answer (score 0):

Use your own implementation of FluentWait in order to wait until text is present after your click:

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait<>(this.driver)
    .withTimeout(driverTimeoutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
    .ignoring(ElementNotVisibleException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function() {
   public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
     return element.getText().length() > 0;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

all thanks for your help the following method seems to of done the trick:

```
    public static void waitForTextToAppearAndClick(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, String textToAppear) throws InterruptedException{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    WebElement locator = element; 
    locator.click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText(textToAppear)));
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(textToAppear)).click();
}
```